# Java issue within connection to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

How can I connect to Microsoft SQL Server from my java code?

Code:

```
public class insert {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LENOVO-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=dbtest";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url , "sa" , "Aa123456");



            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO [dbo].[table] VALUES ('come')");

        }
             catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  System.exit(1);
                }
                catch (SQLException e)
                {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  System.exit(2);
                }

}

     }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at insert.main(insert.java:12)
```

Microsoft SQL Server name is: LENOVO-PC\SQLEXPRESS
and sqljdbc.jar is already added to the referenced libraries.

Comment: Do ypu have driver library in your classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class name `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` you're trying to load is from a very old version of the Microsoft SQL Server 2000 version of the driver. Around 2005, Microsoft changed this to `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` (notice the switch in order between `jdbc` and `sqlserver`). At that time, they also changed the driver URL prefix from `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver:` to `jdbc:sqlserver:`.

In other words, you need to:

1. Use `Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver")` (optional, driver will be loaded automatically)
2. Change your URL to `jdbc:sqlserver://LENOVO-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=dbtest` (note the prefix change and `DatabaseName` -> `databaseName`. See also [Building the Connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017).

With recent JDBC drivers, it is not necessary to explicitly load the driver class in simple Java applications, so instead of step 1, you could also remove the `Class.forName` line.

Also make sure you are using a recent version of the driver, see the [mssql-jdbc project on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/) ([latest stable version](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases/latest) at time of writing is 7.0.0).

Comment: ... and also use a [current release](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/releases) of the driver itself.

Comment: @GordThompson True, but the fact the OP mentioned they are using `sqljdbc.jar` is an indication they are at least using a version newer than the Microsoft SQL Server 2000 JDBC driver (which iirc had `sqlserver.jar` + maybe some other dependencies). I've added an explicit reminder in my answer.

Comment: I also followed the below to enable port 1433:                                             
                      Got to Start->All Programs-> Microsoft SQL Server 2012-> Configuration Tool -> Click SQL Server Configuration Manager ->Expand SQL Server Network Configuration-> Protocol ->Enable TCP/IP Right box

Double Click on TCP/IP and go to IP Adresses Tap and Put port 1433 under TCP port.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the driver class name:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Comment: That in itself will not be enough, as also the URL is wrong.